# Residence permit no. or equivalent on a visa free stay

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, residency

I am a non-EU national currently staying in the country of Georgia on their one-year visa-free program which includes my country. I have been living here for 7 months but do not have any official residence permit, only a lease agreement.

I am applying to enter the EU on a Tourist visa short stay <= 90 days. But I am currently held up in the application asking for the Residence Permit Number or Equivalent.

What do I do in this scenario? I no longer "live" in my home country, but also do not officially hold residence here (unless I am misunderstanding)

Comment: I suspect that the answer may be that your residence in Georgia on the basis of visa-free entry does not permit you to apply. See https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/countries/georgia/travel/applying-for-a-short-stay-schengen-visa, for example. It might help you get an answer if you stated which Schengen country you wish to apply to, and your citizenship.

Answer (score 4):

So the verdict was that the embassy only processes visas for residence permit holders; as a "tourist", I do not check this box and have 2 options:

1. Acquire residence and then apply
2. Return to my home country and apply from there